# WPF element to use for a a Bitmap BackgroundImage with the ability to add child Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, canvas, panel

So I'm using a WinForms application as a guideline for creating a WPF Application that displays nautical charts.  The WinForms application is using a System.Windows.Forms.Panel and sets the BackgroundImage to a dynamically-created Bitmap.  I have the need to add a child Canvas (or alternative Control) to the Panel so that I can display waypoints overlaying the chart.

In WPF, I have tried using a Canvas as a substitute for the Panel, but I was not able to get that to work since it has a Background property accepting a Brush and not a Bitmap.

I have also tried using a WinFormsHost to utilize the System.Windows.Forms.Panel object, but I can't use this to house another control within it.

So what I need is preferably a WPF element I can use without a WinFormsHost that I can use to set the Bitmap BackgroundImage and to add another control with graphics overlayed.

Comment: You want a control to have as a background an image, is this basically it?

Comment: Just a side note: Since i don't really know what exactly you mean "_I'm using a WinForms application as a guideline for creating a WPF Application_", please let me warn you to not apply WinForms programming techniques one-to-one to WPF (this will often lead into a world of hurt and struggle down the line), but rather employ techniques that WPF is well suited for (data bindings, templating, MVVM, ...). On the other hand, if you use the WinForm UI only as a visual reference in how to arrange your UI elements, then please better ignore my superfluous comment... ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo I'm using the sample application from SevenCs on the proper way to handle the images and memory in the application.  The difference is in the controls they are using, which is why I'm using it as a guideline and trying to retro-fit them with the WPF application

Comment: @jeuxjeux20 I need a control to have a backgroundimage and also have children or controls property to add additional elements to the control, like you can do with a Panel in winforms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ImageBrush to set the background https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imagebrush?view=netframework-4.7.2

There is however a great drawback of doeing so as your canvas will not size itself to the size of the image. You could basically use an image behind a Canvas:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="..."/>
    <Canvas ...>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to display a list of something in WPF you generally use an ItemsControl, and this case is no different.

With ItemsControl you can override the panel it uses, and you were correct in choosing a Canvas over a Panel. Setting an image as the background is easy, you just use an ImageBrush instead.

As for your waypoints, I'm guessing you'll need to display other object types as well, so create a ViewModel for each and use a DataTemplate to select the appropriate graphic depending on the type. Each graphic that gets created will be wrapped up in a ContentPresenter, but ItemsControl also allows you to override the style of that via ItemContainerStyle, so that's where you set Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top to position your items.

Put it all together and your XAML needs to look something like this:

```
<Viewbox>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ChartElements}" Width="1000" Height="1000">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <!-- DataTemplates here select the appropriate graphic to display for each class type -->
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Waypoint}">
                <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Yellow" Stroke="CornflowerBlue" StrokeThickness="5">
                    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="-25" Y="-25" /> <!-- center the ellipse -->
                    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                </Ellipse>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NavigationLine}">
                <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="{Binding Width}" Y2="{Binding Height}" Stroke="CornflowerBlue" StrokeThickness="10" StrokeDashArray="3 1" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <!-- Replace the default panel with a Canvas -->
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas>
                    <Canvas.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1%2Bp%2BB8wq2L._SL1500_.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" />
                    </Canvas.Background>
                </Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <!-- Position each item on the canvas and set the ZIndex so that waypoints appear on top -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding Layer}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Viewbox>
```

You should always be creating a MainViewModel and doing proper MVVM, but this sample code will get you started:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<object> ChartElements { get; } = new List<object>
    {
        new Waypoint{X=100, Y=100 },
        new Waypoint{X=500, Y=300 },
        new Waypoint{X=300, Y=500 },
        new Waypoint{X=800, Y=700 },

        new NavigationLine{X1=100, Y1=100, X2=500, Y2=300},
        new NavigationLine{X1=500, Y1=300, X2=300, Y2=500},
        new NavigationLine{X1=300, Y1=500, X2=800, Y2=700}
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}

public class Waypoint
{
    public int Layer { get; } = 1; // waypoint circles should always appear on top
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}

public class NavigationLine
{
    public int Layer { get; } = 0;
    public double X1 { get; set; }
    public double Y1 { get; set; }
    public double X2 { get; set; }
    public double Y2 { get; set; }

    public double X => this.X1;
    public double Y => this.Y1;
    public double Width => this.X2 - this.X1;
    public double Height => this.Y2 - this.Y1;
}
```

The hot-linked image will probably take a few seconds to load, but you should wind up with this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could probably save a lot of work by using one of the map control libraries available for WPF. I can recommend my [XAML Map Control](https://github.com/ClemensFischer/XAML-Map-Control). It provides several ways to display map bitmaps, and also has a `MapItemsControl` to easily display collections of items with geographic locations.

The probably easiest way to show a nautical chart is to use a `WmsImageLayer`:

```
xmlns:map="clr-namespace:MapControl;assembly=MapControl.WPF"
...
<map:Map Center="50,0" ZoomLevel="2">
    <map:Map.MapLayer>
        <map:WmsImageLayer ServiceUri="http://chartserver4.sevencs.com:8080"
                           Layers="ENC"/>
    </map:Map.MapLayer>
</map:Map>
```

If you do not have a WMS for chart generation (like the SevenCs ChartServer), but need to convert a WinForms bitmap, you may derive from the `MapImageLayer` class:

```
public class ChartImageLayer : MapImageLayer
{
    protected override Task<ImageSource> GetImageAsync(BoundingBox boundingBox)
    {
        // use ParentMap.MapProjection to get the current map projection

        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // get SevenCs chart bitmap for the requested bounding box
            System.Drawing.Bitmap chartBitmap = ...

            // convert from System.Drawing.Bitmap to System.Windows.Media.ImageSource
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                chartBitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                stream.Position = 0;

                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
                bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapImage.EndInit();
                bitmapImage.Freeze();
                return (ImageSource)bitmapImage;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and use the class like this:

```
<map:Map Center="50,0" ZoomLevel="2">
    <map:Map.MapLayer>
        <local:ChartImageLayer />
    </map:Map.MapLayer>
</map:Map>
```

---

For displaying collections of of items, you would create a view model, e.g. like this:

```
using MapControl;
...

public class Waypoint
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Waypoint> Waypoints { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Waypoint>();
}
```

with some initialization like:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    vm.Waypoints.Add(new Waypoint { Label = "Iceland", Location = new Location(65, -18) });
    vm.Waypoints.Add(new Waypoint { Label = "Norway", Location = new Location(71, 25) });
    vm.Waypoints.Add(new Waypoint { Label = "Cyprus", Location = new Location(35, 33) });
    vm.Waypoints.Add(new Waypoint { Label = "Tenerife", Location = new Location(28.25, -16.5) });

    DataContext = vm;
}
```

In XAML, you would add a MapItemsControl like this:

```
<map:Map Center="50,0" ZoomLevel="2">
    ...
    <map:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Waypoints}">
        <map:MapItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="map:MapItem">
                <Setter Property="map:MapPanel.Location" Value="{Binding Location}"/>
            </Style>
        </map:MapItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <map:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas>
                    <Path Fill="Red">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,-5" Text="{Binding Label}"/>
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </map:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </map:MapItemsControl>
</map:Map>
```

The result:

[image]

Zoomed in:

[image]